# Change the last value of all column names of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, r-colnames

I have a dataframe, which looks like follows:

```
# Example data
data <- data.frame(x1.1 = rnorm(10),
                   x2.1 = rnorm(10),
                   x3.1 = rnorm(10))
```

I want to change the last value ".1" of all column names to ".2". It is important to find a general solution, since I will have to perform this for several big dataframes.

```
# Desired output:
colnames(data)
# "x1.2" "x2.2" "x3.2"
```

I can do that with a complicated loop, but I am sure there must be an easier way, which I am not able to find. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Try `colnames(data) <- sub(".1$",".2",colnames(data))`

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You don't need the `.`, using `1$` and `2` will suffice

Comment: Ah yes you are right, thanks for the improvement!